# Doctrine one to many - persisting multiple files from owning side not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 2 entities  Submission  and Documents.  1 Submission can have Multiple documents. 
Submission Entity:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Document", mappedBy="submission",cascade={"persist", "remove" })
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="submission_id")
   */
  protected $document;


  /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getDocument()
  {
    return $this->document->toArray();
  }

  public function setDocument(Document $document)
  {
    $this->document[] = $document;

    return $this;
  }
```

Document Entity:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Submission", inversedBy="document")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="submission_id", referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="cascade", nullable=true)
   */
  protected $submission;

  public function getSubmission()
  {
    return $this->submission;
  }

  /**
   * @param mixed $submission
   */
  public function setSubmission($submission)
  {
    $this->submission = $submission;
  }
```

After receiving files dropzonejs - I'm saving   them into Document object, and then, i'm try to save this object into Submission, and persist.

```
$document = new Document();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$media = $request->files->get('file');
foreach($media as $req){
  $document->setFile($req);
  $document->setPath($req->getPathName());
  $document->setName($req->getClientOriginalName());
  $em->persist($document);
} 

    $submission->setSubmissionStatus(true);
      foreach($document as $item){
        $submission->setDocument($item);
      }
    $submission->setUser($user);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($submission);
    $em->flush();
```

Problem is that all the time, i'm receiving error that  submission_title is not set, but that's not true, because i have set this field before. I haven't got idea, what is  wrong.

Comment: Only first file  from a queue is stored into DB

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll get some mileage out of following the tutorial over at http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html, if you haven't already.

I can see that your getters / setters aren't optimal for associating more than one `Document` with your `Submission`.

As they write in the Symfony docs, where they want to associate one category with many products, they have the following code:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Category.php

// ...
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Category
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

From the docs:

> The code in the constructor is important. Rather than being
>   instantiated as a traditional array, the $products property must be of
>   a type that implements Doctrine's Collection interface. In this case,
>   an ArrayCollection object is used. This object looks and acts almost
>   exactly like an array, but has some added flexibility. If this makes
>   you uncomfortable, don't worry. Just imagine that it's an array and
>   you'll be in good shape.

So, you'll want to be sure the constructor for your `Document` entity has something like `$this->submissions = new ArrayCollection();`. I've changed the property to a plural name, because I think it's more semantically correct. But you can keep your `$submission` property name, if you like.

Next is to add a `addSubmission`, `removeSubmission`, and a `getSubmissions` method.

Then, your class might end up looking like this:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Submission.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Submission 
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Document", mappedBy="submission",cascade={"persist", "remove" })
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="submission_id")
     * 
     * @var ArrayCollection()
     */
    protected $documents;

    ...

    /**
     * Instantiates the Submission Entity
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->documents = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Returns all documents on the Submission
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDocuments()
    {
        return $this->documents;
    }

    /**
     * Add document to this Submission
     * 
     * @param Document $document The object to add to the $documents collection.
     *
     * @return Submission
     */
    public function setDocument(Document $document)
    {
        $this->documents[] = $document;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a document from this Submission
     * 
     * @param Document $document The object to remove from the $documents collection.
     *
     * @return Submission
     */
    public function removeDocument(Document $document)
    {
        $this->documents->removeElement($document);

        return $this;
    }
}
```